# How to block client listening on a server or the port the client is listening to

Tags: java, linux, tcp

Is a there a way to block messages on a port in linux (or Programmatically)?.

Say I have a server 'S' and a client 'C'. If the client is sending messages on post 12345, a linux command  yield below like this:

```
 lsof -i | grep 12345

 java     52148 john.doe   26w  IPv6 1041861063      0t0  TCP  localhost:53413->localhost:12345 (ESTABLISHED)
 java     52164 john.doe    5u  IPv6 1041861064      0t0  TCP localhost:11400->localhost:12345 (ESTABLISHED)
 java     52164 john.doe   46r  IPv6 1041860804      0t0  TCP localhost:12345 (LISTEN)
```

Is there a way to block the client from sending messages to the server? Or is there a way to block the port(12345) that client is sending messages through to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controlling access to TCP/IP ports is the responsibility of your Firewall.  This is done with [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) under Linux.

For example to stop incoming connections to your server, use the following command on the machine that is running the server.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 12345 -j DROP
```

To stop outgoing connections from the server to the client use

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --destination-port 12345 -j DROP
```

To do this on a per IP basis use

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d {ip_address} --dport 12345 -j DROP
```

oh and don't forget to

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

when you're done.